# Proof by mathematical induction that $1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+...+(1+2+3+...+n)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Prove by induction that for all positive integer values of $n$:

$$1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + \ldots + (1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n) = \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6}$$

Please help with this proof by mathematical induction.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  $\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^m i=\sum\limits_{m=1}^n(\frac{m^2}2+\frac m2)=\frac12\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\frac12\frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac12n(n+1)(\frac{2n+1}6+\frac12)=\frac12n(n+1)(\frac{2n+4}6)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6$

Comment: Please also add what you tried on this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you [prove the hockey-stick identity by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity#Inductive_proof), the desired result is a corollary:$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^jj=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{j+1}{2}=\binom{n+2}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If the $n$-th term is $a_n$, then
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+(1+2+\dots+n+(n+1))=a_n+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$
By the induction hypothesis,
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$
I guess you can finish.

Of course you need to know that
$$
1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
which you can prove by induction as well.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- From the given formula
$$1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) + \ldots + (1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n) = \frac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6}$$ you have  $\dfrac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6}+(1+2+3+\cdots+n)$ so you can apply induction verifiant that $$\dfrac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ is equal to $\dfrac{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}{6}$
(obviously you have used the quite known formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural integers.